# Make NPM search in both private and public registry

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, bower, node-modules

In Bower I can do the following within a `.bowerrc` file to search multiple registries for a module:

```
  "registry": {
  "search": [
        "https://private/repo/name",
        "https://bower.herokuapp.com"
  ]
},
```

Is there a similar way of how this can also be done with NPM? I know there's the `.npmrc` file but I can't seem to find a way of how to specify more than one registry so that the system will search in both.

Comment: Admittedly, I don't know the answer to your question, so the reason I'm writing this comment is to mention `jspm` and its ability to search `npm` repositories as well as define custom ones. I'll leave the comment, in case someone finds `jspm` useful the same way I did. [Website](http://jspm.io/). Good luck getting the answer!

Comment: Just 2 days ago i had a conversation with a friend who did exactly what you want with -> https://github.com/rlidwka/sinopia